# Finding a point on B-spline

Tags: geometry, algorithms, bezier-curve, spline

I would like to find a point on B-spline.
For Bezier curves, only control points and degree of curve are needed find coordinates of point $u$,
$$ C(u) = \sum_{i=0}^n B_{n,i}(u) P_i $$
$$ B_{n,i}(u) = \frac {n!}{i! (n-i)!} u^i (1-u)^{n-i}$$
$$ 0 \le u \le 1 $$
For B-spline, how do I find (x,y) coordinates of a point on it? Do I need to consider knot values and fit points in calculation beside control points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider knot values when evaluating a point on a b-spline curve from a given parameter as that it is part of the b-spline curve definition. You don't need to consider fit points which are merely used to construct the b-spline curve.

Comment: Can I use [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/B-Spline.html) to find the point on B-spline? or do I need to [insert knots](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/single-insertion.html) to find the coordinates?

Comment: @OP: yes, you can use the recursive formula in the link to find point on a b-spline curve. This is called Cox deBoor recursive formula. You don't need to insert knots.

Comment: Do I need to change the knot vectors to simple form if the maximum value is not 1? For example, in this knot vectors $U = [ 0, 0, 0, 70, 140, 140, 140]$, do I need to change to knot vectors $U = [0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1]$ to find half point,P(0.5), on B-Spline curve?

Comment: You don't have to normalize the knot vector for evaluating points on the curve.